# android studio components not showing while designing activity

Tags: android-studio, components

Well I am new to android studio and when I created my first hello world app. I couldn't see hello world text-view. I dragged other components such as button and still nothing showed up in design or blueprints. But when I built hello world app. App showed hello world text-view in emulator. I have searched a lot in internet but couldn't find any solution.

I have attached a screen shot below.

[image: Screen shot after adding button in hello world activity]

Android Studio is generating following error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:180)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:61)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:118)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:213)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(ActionBarContainer.java:62)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:481)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:264)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:222)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:209)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:337)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:348)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:248)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:863)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.BridgeActionBar.<init>(BridgeActionBar.java:89)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.bars.AppCompatActionBar.<init>(AppCompatActionBar.java:68)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.createActionBar(Layout.java:277)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.Layout.<init>(Layout.java:161)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:288)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:384)
at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:193)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:544)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$3(RenderTask.java:678)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and here is the screenshot

[image: error image]

Comment: There is a small red exclamation mark. This indicates that Android Studio has encountered some problem and is unable to render the layout. You can click on the exclamation mark to find out what is wrong (not having built the project is only one thing which might cause a problem)

Comment: @0X0nosugar Thanks for reply. I clicked on exclamation and it showed an error I have edited my question.Could you help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While in start I used @ChaithanyaKrishna proposed method, later on I found that still problem is not resolved properly. Some Layouts such Drawer-layout will not render properly and solution to this problem is to lower your SDK level to 26. This resolves most of rendering issues.

I had changed my SDK and dependencies level in build.Gradle (Module:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
   compileSdkVersion 26
   defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.itnoa.asdf"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
     release {
       minifyEnabled false
       proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
     }
}
}

dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
  implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.0-alpha3'
  implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I have faced the same issue but resolved it by making a small change in **styles.xml** file which you can find in resources(res) directory.

Change Parent from "*Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar*" to "*Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar*".

Comment: Hi @Chaithanya did you use drawer layout. The above mentioned solution worked for empty activity but now I'm facing same issue with - android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout. Any help would be prefered. Thanks in advance

Comment: Even I am very new to android. I resolved my issue with that solution but don't know for that layout exactly. This resource may be helpful to you check it out once https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/DrawerLayout

Answer (score 7):

Problem in Apptheme setting . Change from Default AppTheme to something else. It will work .
Check the screenshot i marked the Apptheme location . just change default to something else.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: @P Kumarasamy Thanks man that helped a lot but could you explain why default theme is causing this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Wasted 4 hours on this yesterday trying to figure out why I could see nothing in design view. Wish I could up-vote your answer more than once.

Comment: Agree with @birwin, This was driving me nuts - I'm still nuts, but now happy nuts.

Answer (score 2):

Find Styles.xml in Values.(res/Values/Styles.xml) Change this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

to this:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

Then clean and build project. Both of those you can do from build menu.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

In **res>values>styles.xml**

change:

```
Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
```

to

```
Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
```

Answer (score 0):

I just fixed this problem by deleting the layout file and again creating it.
I tried all above mentioned methods, but none worked for me.
I hope it may help someone.